Specifying Python for using Pybind11 from Makefile: "Python.h: No such file or directory"
I am trying to use PyBind11 with my C++ program, but can't figure out how to correctly specify the Makefile (I can't use CMake with this program).
My Makefile looks like this:
program = mlfe

include $(JIVEDIR)/makefiles/prog.mk
include $(JIVEDIR)/makefiles/packages/*.mk

MY_LIBS += boost_filesystem boost_system
MY_INCDIRS += Eigen

MY_INCDIRS += /home/<username>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include $(shell python3 -m pybind11 --includes)

(I first tried it from a container, but after failing there I moved to my system python installation)
When compiling, I get the following error:
example.cpp:137:
/home/<username>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pybind11/include/pybind11/detail/../detail/common.h:274:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
  274 | #include <Python.h>

python3-dev is installed correctly. I can also compile the example of the pybind11 docs without any errors, making me believe it is a problem with my Makefile.
I've tried adding additional commands to the Makefile, but without succes:
PYTHON_LIBS = $(shell python3-config --libs)
PYTHON_CFLAGS = $(shell python3-config --cflags)
CXXFLAGS += $(MY_INCDIRS:%=-I%) # $(PYTHON_CFLAGS)
LDFLAGS += $(MY_LIBS) $(PYTHON_LIBS)

EDIT: Thank you @John Bollinger for pointing out what was wrong. I'm not sure exactly how to implement it. I've added the following line to the Makefile
MY_INCDIRS += /usr/include/python3.10

which has resolved this error.
However, a new error shows it still can't find the Python references correctly:
FE2Material.cpp:(.text+0x10968): undefined reference to `PyType_IsSubtype'
/usr/bin/ld: FE2Material.cpp:(.text+0x10d1e): undefined reference to `_Py_Dealloc'
/usr/bin/ld: FE2Material.cpp:(.text+0x10db1): undefined reference to `_Py_Dealloc'
usr/bin/ld: FE2Material.cpp:(.text+0x16aff): undefined reference to `Py_IsInitialized'
/usr/bin/ld: FE2Material.cpp:(.text+0x16b1d): undefined reference to `PyConfig_SetBytesArgv'
/usr/bin/ld: FE2Material.cpp:(.text+0x16b41): undefined reference to `PyStatus_Exception'
...


Python.h should be provided by python3-dev, but it is not normally in the default include file search path.  The default location depends on python version.  You need to add an -I option specifying that directory.

Thank you for the response @JohnBollinger. I've edited my question with what I tried based on it, but I don't really understand what you mean. How exactly would I specify this option?
